# After a timeout, kill the process and all its subprocesses

Tags: linux, bash, process, signals

I know there is a [doalarm](http://gnu.gds.tuwien.ac.at/directory/sysadmin/misc/doalarm.html) program which can kill the spawned process after a timeout. Is there a way to kill all its subprocesses as well?

Comment: Do you want to do this in the command line or in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your application run in a new session using [`setsid <app> ...`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setsid.1.html). That is also going to make the process a group leader.

And [when the group leader terminates](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html):

> If the process is a controlling process, the SIGHUP signal shall be sent to each process in the foreground process group of the controlling terminal belonging to the calling process.